# asp ModalPopupExtender is getting closed when page is getting postback

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, postback

I am using asp ModalPopupExtender to display a treeview in asp.net page. When I click a button a ModalPopupExtender will be raised and loads the treeview with checkbox( loading treeview is a usercontrol ascx). In that usercontrol I have written some server side code for when I check a parent node all the child nodes should be checked. Fot this my page will get postback. My problem is when my page gets post back my ModalPopupExtender is getting off and on and my functions are working fine.

here is my treeview in ascx page

```
 <asp:TreeView ID="tvFolderSelect" runat="server" RootNodeStyle-ForeColor="Black"
    CssClass="foldertree" LeafNodeStyle-ForeColor="Black" LeafNodeStyle-Font-Bold="false"
    ParentNodeStyle-ForeColor="Black" Width="100%" Style="margin: 3px 0 0 -16px;"
    OnTreeNodePopulate="tvFolderSelect_TreeNodePopulate" OnTreeNodeCheckChanged="tvFolderSelect_TreeNodeCheckChanged" onclick="postbackOnCheck(event);"
    ShowCheckBoxes="All" >
  <LeafNodeStyle Font-Bold="False" ForeColor="Black" CssClass="foldertreeleafnode"
        ImageUrl="~/images/img_dms/sm_fldr.png"  />
    <ParentNodeStyle Font-Italic="True" ImageUrl="~/images/img_dms/sm_fldr.png" Font-Underline="True"
        CssClass="foldertreeparentnode"/>
    <NodeStyle Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalPadding="0px"
        NodeSpacing="0px" VerticalPadding="0px" />
    <RootNodeStyle ForeColor="Black" CssClass="foldertreerootnode" />
    <SelectedNodeStyle Font-Underline="False" HorizontalPadding="0px" VerticalPadding="0px" />
</asp:TreeView>
```

and here is the javascript function to get postback

```
 function postbackOnCheck(e) {
    var evt = e || window.event;
    var o = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
    if (o.tagName == 'INPUT' && o.type == 'checkbox' && o.name != null && o.name.indexOf('CheckBox') > -1) {
       __doPostBack("", "");
    }
}
```

Here is I am using the control

```
  <img id="AddActivity" runat="server" src="../images/plus1.gif" alt="" style="text-align: right;
                                cursor: pointer; float: right; padding: 1%;" />
                            <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="MPEACT" runat="server" TargetControlID="AddActivity"
                                PopupControlID="ACTDiv" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" />
```

How can I stop getting invisibility of the ajax popup.

Comment: Can you post the markup rendered in your browser when the page is completely loaded...there are scripts injected into your web page after certain point. I am interested in anything that takes time to load prior to that script getting executed...

Comment: Did you try using update panel for postback? That way you will get the expected result.

Comment: Here is a link http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/overview/updatepaneloverview.aspx at the bottom of the page you can find a few examples also.

Comment: share the rendered html in pastebin.com or some similar service.

Comment: here is my HTML   http://pastebin.com/MYPuG0hH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used AsyncPostBackTrigger to run the server side code and changed the __DoPostBack method parameters. now my treeview design is

```
<div id="form" runat="server">
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updTree" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TreeView ID="tvFolderSelect" runat="server" RootNodeStyle-ForeColor="Black"
            CssClass="foldertree" LeafNodeStyle-ForeColor="Black" LeafNodeStyle-Font-Bold="false"
            ParentNodeStyle-ForeColor="Black" Width="100%" Style="margin: 3px 0 0 -16px;"
            OnTreeNodePopulate="tvFolderSelect_TreeNodePopulate" OnTreeNodeCheckChanged="tvFolderSelect_TreeNodeCheckChanged"
            ShowCheckBoxes="All" onclick="postbackOnCheck(event);">
            <LeafNodeStyle Font-Bold="False" ForeColor="Black" CssClass="foldertreeleafnode"
                ImageUrl="~/images/img_dms/sm_fldr.png" />
            <ParentNodeStyle Font-Italic="True" ImageUrl="~/images/img_dms/sm_fldr.png" Font-Underline="True"
                CssClass="foldertreeparentnode" />
            <NodeStyle Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalPadding="0px"
                NodeSpacing="0px" VerticalPadding="0px" />
            <RootNodeStyle ForeColor="Black" CssClass="foldertreerootnode" />
            <SelectedNodeStyle Font-Underline="False" HorizontalPadding="0px" VerticalPadding="0px" />
        </asp:TreeView>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="tvFolderSelect" EventName="TreeNodeCheckChanged" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and the function to postback is

```
  function postbackOnCheck(e) {
    var evt = e || window.event;
    var o = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
    if (o.tagName == 'INPUT' && o.type == 'checkbox' && o.name != null && o.name.indexOf('CheckBox') > -1) {
        __doPostBack('<%=updTree.ClientID %>', 'Refresh:0,1,2');
    }
}
```

Now my panel is not closing while getting postback

Answer (score 1):

here is what I did to re-create your issue. I've created a web page with a modal popup extender.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ModalPopExample.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApp.ModalPopup.ModalPopExample" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .hide
        {
            display:block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
        <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" CssClass="hide" runat="server" BorderColor="Red" BorderStyle="Dashed" BorderWidth="3px">
            Are you sure?
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="btnok" runat="server" Text="OK" />
            <asp:Button ID="btncancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" />
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Button ID="btnShow" runat="server" Text="Show Modal" />
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl="~/image_loader.ashx" runat="server" />
        <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="btnShow_ModalPopupExtender" DropShadow="true" OkControlID="btnok" CancelControlID="btncancel" PopupControlID="Panel1" runat="server" DynamicServicePath="" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="btnShow">
        </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>        
    </form>
    <script>
        var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
        prm.add_pageLoaded(function () {
            console.log('loaded');
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Notice that the image is loaded via a handler file (ashx):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApp.ModalPopup
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for image_loader
    /// </summary>
    public class image_loader : IHttpHandler
    {

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
            var imagePath = context.Server.MapPath("~/images/windows_xp_bliss-wide.jpg");
            Thread.Sleep(20000);
            context.Response.TransmitFile(imagePath);
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The popup flickers for a while. The most simple workaround you can do is hide the element at first itself (via css) and some javascript is required to remove that css when the web page if fully loaded.

```
    <style type="text/css">
        .hide
        {
            display:none;
        }
    </style>
```

When you ajax client scripts all finish loading...find the control and remove the above class on the element.

```
<script>
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_pageLoaded(function () {
        console.log('loaded');
        var div = document.getElementById('Panel1');
        div.className = '';
    });
</script>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: My doubt is, I am writing   __doPostBack("", ""); for getting postback onclick of treeview in another page( ascx usercontrol). But we are displaying the ascx page in another(main) page via modelpopupextender.Now the   __doPostBack("", ""); method is applying for main page not for that ascx page I guess.. What do you say ??

Comment: Added you in Google+ :) I am Naresh Jadapalli.

Comment: Ascx is supposed to be thought of something like a "reusable" component. Its not a page in itself. Anyway I don't quite follow how your problem has run into page postbacks. It was never part of the original question. Seems like you need to open another question out here.

Comment: A word of advice: don't just post a question because you are stuck. Try to present a "fake" problem which "models" your actual problem. It helps us re-create the issue you are facing and also helps people out here to provide better answers. And when you are at it, chances are that you might itself figure out a solution. :)

Comment: And I tried this in Javascript .. Please have a look on it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21985699/checked-property-not-working-in-treeview-checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

Try to use update panel and refer below link for detail why Modalpopup close on postback?

http://patelshailesh.com/index.php/why-does-modalpopup-close-on-postback

Comment: I tried this. Still it is behaving like before. My doubt is, I am writing __doPostBack("", ""); for getting postback onclick of treeview in another page( ascx usercontrol). But we are displaying the ascx page in another(main) page via modelpopupextender.Now the __doPostBack("", ""); method is applying for main page not for that ascx page I guess.. What do you say ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use this JavaScript function on button click:

```
<script>
                $("#btn").click(
                   function () {
                       window.top.location = "WebForm1.aspx";
                   });
</script>
```

I had used this function to auto update a grid on closing the Popup, if you want to see that Article and want to see how I had used this function then you can refer to this link:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cd7c2e/how-to-auto-refresh-grid-view-on-closing-of-popup-menu/

Many other Articles and similar forums can be found on http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/

Comment: Sorry I am not looking for this. I am using an usercontrol, inside that I have a treeview which will get postback after checking the nodes. That control is being displaying in a modelpopupextender. Now the popup is being close and open when the postback occurs