# checked property not working in treeview checkboxes

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, treeview, modalpopupextender

I have a treeview, I want to check all the children when I clicked the parent node from javascript. I have followed [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437617/asp-net-treeview-checkbox-selection/1437655#1437655) from stackoverflow. This process is currect. I have tested it with alert message also. [image] The ID which is showing in the alert message is exactly right ID of the child. And the method is been setting the status also. Code is reaching here `childChkBoxes[i].checked = check;`

```
function CheckUncheckChildren(childContainer, check) {
    var childChkBoxes = childContainer.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var childChkBoxCount = childChkBoxes.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < childChkBoxCount; i++) {
        alert("Childer lenght = "+childChkBoxes.length +"     childern ID  "+ childChkBoxes[i].id + "        Parent checked state =" + check);          
        childChkBoxes[i].checked = check;
    }
}
```

even the check box of child is not been checking in UI. What might be the problem. **This code is working for every one.** Why not working here, I am displaying the treeview in a modelpopupextender control. Is anything wrong with my browser, I am using firefox. Is anything wrong with my treeview design.
her it is

```
 <asp:TreeView ID="tvFolderSelect" runat="server" RootNodeStyle-ForeColor="Black"
    CssClass="foldertree" LeafNodeStyle-ForeColor="Black" LeafNodeStyle-Font-Bold="false"
    ParentNodeStyle-ForeColor="Black" Width="100%" Style="margin: 3px 0 0 -16px;"
    OnTreeNodePopulate="tvFolderSelect_TreeNodePopulate" onclick="OnTreeClick(event);"
    ShowCheckBoxes="All" >
  <LeafNodeStyle Font-Bold="False" ForeColor="Black" CssClass="foldertreeleafnode"
        ImageUrl="~/images/img_dms/sm_fldr.png"  />
    <ParentNodeStyle Font-Italic="True" ImageUrl="~/images/img_dms/sm_fldr.png" Font-Underline="True"
        CssClass="foldertreeparentnode"/>
    <NodeStyle Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalPadding="0px"
        NodeSpacing="0px" VerticalPadding="0px" />
    <RootNodeStyle ForeColor="Black" CssClass="foldertreerootnode" />
    <SelectedNodeStyle Font-Underline="False" HorizontalPadding="0px" VerticalPadding="0px" />
</asp:TreeView>
```

**I tried this code in normal aspx page(not in modelpopupextender). And it is working well**

Comment: Hi. Is this issue anything related with your previous post? Are you simply trying to check/uncheck all the checkboxes of the selected node and its children based on the selected node's state - checked or unchecked?

Comment: It is related to my previous post only. But I just tried the same task in javascript, because that was getting postback and the popup was closing. In javascript I have followed the above link. It is checking the child nodes, but not able to see in UI. If I loop through all the nodes, I am able to get the checked property values exactly..

Comment: The modal popup will disappear on postback. If you don't want that to happen consider wrapping your treeview in an updatepanel. As for checking/unchecking this would be easier in the server side.

Comment: @deostroll:  I have done that with UpdatePanel. Thank you :). But I still don't know, why the checked property not working with javascript.

Comment: I am able to home in on a checkbox in the developer tools window (IE). And via console I can check/uncheck that particular checkbox. And that is visible on the ui. Provided the modal popup is active. How is your function invoked.?

Comment: I am able to check that particulare checkbox, but not all the children under that checkbox. I am calling the function onclick of treeview like   onclick="OnTreeClick(event);"

Comment: Have a look at this: http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2006/03/25/73300.aspx